# Promotion banner in application

Tags: facebook-credits, promotions

Playing in my aplication, appear in the right panel, one Promotion about obtain Facebook credits to be played in my application. I don't allow that promotion and obviously, there is not necessary Facebook credits to play in my application. Who is the responsible of that banner and how could I contact with them and delete this banner?

After click in the promotion, it will appear this screen to buy Facebook Credits. I'm worry about phising campaign and the last point I would like is that my players will take a wrong idea about the game and the political of the game and the company.

Is there any way to delete these promiotions?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does it automatically based on their own secret algorithm.  I am unaware of any option for disabling it.

I never saw one on my app before I implemented Credits.  Are you saying you are seeing it show up even though you have not implemented Facebook Credits?  I would think that would be worthy of opening a bug with Facebook.